# How can i shorten this code and make it less repetitive?

Tags: java

I made a simple calculator but the if statements are very repetitive and long. I am wondering what other solution I could use to shorten it and make it less repetitive. For example using a method (which i have tried but not succeeded) or any other techniques that are usable. Preferably not too advanced since I'm a beginner.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
import static java.lang.Integer.*;

public class SimpleCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String operator = showInputDialog("Choose operation: " + "\n" +
                "[1] = Plus" + "\n" +
                "[2] = Minus" + "\n" +
                "[3] = Multiply" + "\n" +
                "[4] = Divide" + "\n");

        int c = parseInt(operator);

        if (c > 4) {
            showMessageDialog(null, "You cant do that.");

        } else if (c == 1) {
            String textA = showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
            String textB = showInputDialog("Enter second number: ");
            int a = parseInt(textA);
            int b = parseInt(textB);
            showMessageDialog(null, a + " + " + b + " = " + (a + b));

        } else if (c == 2) {
            String textA = showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
            String textB = showInputDialog("Enter second number: ");
            int a = parseInt(textA);
            int b = parseInt(textB);
            showMessageDialog(null, a + " - " + b + " = " + (a - b));

        } else if (c == 3) {
            String textA = showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
            String textB = showInputDialog("Enter second number: ");
            int a = parseInt(textA);
            int b = parseInt(textB);
            showMessageDialog(null, a + " * " + b + " = " + (a * b));

        } else if (c == 4) {
            String textA = showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
            String textB = showInputDialog("Enter second number: ");
            int a = parseInt(textA);
            int b = parseInt(textB);
            showMessageDialog(null, a + " / " + b + " = " + (a / b));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: use switch case and follow S.O.L.I.D. prociples. https://java2blog.com/solid-principles-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
        String textA = showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
        String textB = showInputDialog("Enter second number: ");
        int a = parseInt(textA);
        int b = parseInt(textB);
        switch(c) {
        case 1:
            showMessageDialog(null, a + " + " + b + " = " + (a+b));
            break;

        case 2:
        ...
        default:
            showMessageDialog(null, "You cant do that.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, to start; you can move the

```
      String textA = showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
      String textB = showInputDialog("Enter second number: ");
      int a = parseInt(textA);
      int b = parseInt(textB);
```

outside of the if blocks so that it only asks once *before* the if block, which will save you 12 lines of code.

Or you can also use methods or functions as a practice; but that wouldn't shorten your code further, really. I'd also suggest looking into Codegolf, you can learn a LOT about code-shortening.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple approaches:

- Put the common code into a method
- Move the common code to a different part of the current method so that it is executed unconditionally.
- Put the non-common code into a function / method / class that can be used to parameterize the common code.

---

In this case, the second approach works best; e.g.

```
  if(c==1) {
          String textA = showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
          String textB = showInputDialog("Enter second number: ");
          int a = parseInt(textA);
          int b = parseInt(textB);
          showMessageDialog(null, a + " + " + b + " = " + (a+b));
  } 
  else if (c==2) {
          String textA = showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
          String textB = showInputDialog("Enter second number: ");
          int a = parseInt(textA);
          int b = parseInt(textB);
          showMessageDialog(null, a + " - " + b + " = " + (a-b));
  } 
  ...
```

can be transformed into:

```
  String textA = showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
  String textB = showInputDialog("Enter second number: ");
  int a = parseInt(textA);
  int b = parseInt(textB);
  int result;
  char op;

  if (c == 1) {
      result = a + b;
      op = '+';
  } else if (c == 2) {
      result = a - b;
      op = '-';
  } 
  ...

  showMessageDialog(null, a + " " + op + " " + b + " = " + result);
```

(I have left a problem there for you to notice and sort out ... as a learning exercise.)

Answer (score 1):

The following will be identical, but doesn't repeat the same lines over and over.  You can also use the switch statement in place of the 4 if/else if statements.

```
public class SimpleCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String operator = showInputDialog("Choose operation: " + "\n" + 
                                          "[1] = Plus" + "\n" +
                                          "[2] = Minus" + "\n" + 
                                          "[3] = Multiply" + "\n" +
                                          "[4] = Divide" + "\n");
        int c = parseInt(operator);
        if (c>4) {
            showMessageDialog(null, "You cant do that.");
            return;
        }
        String textA = showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
        String textB = showInputDialog("Enter second number: ");
        int a = parseInt(textA);
        int b = parseInt(textB);
        if(c==1) {
            showMessageDialog(null, a + " + " + b + " = " + (a+b));
        } 
        else if (c==2) {
            showMessageDialog(null, a + " - " + b + " = " + (a-b));
        } 
        else if (c==3) {
            showMessageDialog(null, a + " * " + b + " = " + (a*b));
        } 
        else if (c==4) {
            showMessageDialog(null, a + " / " + b + " = " + (a/b));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun.  Factor out the stuff that's common!  And handle the possibility that you'll need to implement unary operators.  You'll probably also want to put it in a loop, and add an exit command.

```
public class SimpleCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String operator = showInputDialog(
                "Choose operation: " + "\n" + 
                "[1] = Add" + "\n" +
                "[2] = Subtract" + "\n" + 
                "[3] = Multiply" + "\n" +
                "[4] = Divide" + "\n");
                "[5] = Negate" + "\n");

        int c = parseInt(operator);

        int operand_count = 0;
        switch (c) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                operand_count = 2;
                break;
            case 5:
                operand_count = 1;
                break;
            default:
                showMessageDialog(null, "You cant do that.");
                return(-1);
        }

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;

        if (operand_count >= 1) {
            String textA = showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
            int a = parseInt(textA);
        }
        if (operand_count >= 2) {
            String textB = showInputDialog("Enter second number: ");
            int b = parseInt(textB);
        }

        char * opname = "";
        int result = 0;

        switch (c) {
            case 1:
                opname = "+";
                result = a + b;
                break;
            case 2:
                opname = "-";
                result = a - b;
                break;
            case 3:
                opname = "*";
                result = a * b;
                break;
            case 4:
                opname = "/";
                result = a / b;
                break;
            case 5:
                opname = "-";
                result = -a;
                break;
        }

        if (operand_count == 1) {
            showMessageDialog(null, opname + " (" + a + ") = " result);
        } else {
            showMessageDialog(null, a + " " + opname + " " + b + " = " + result);
        }
    }    
}
```